# auth for local dev server doesn't work

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web.xml

I am setting up a java/GAE/angular app engine project and am attempting to require login at certain paths. I am allowing google to handle the auth and I'm seeing a nullpointer that appears to originate from the provided `com.google.appengine.api.users.dev.LocalLoginServlet.java`.If i deploy the project to app engine, there is no problem.

Here's the relevant part of my web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Require Admin</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Here's the stacktrace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.google.appengine.api.users.dev.LoginCookieUtils.encodeEmailAsUserId(LoginCookieUtils.java:90)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.users.dev.LoginCookieUtils.createCookie(LoginCookieUtils.java:42)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.users.dev.LocalLoginServlet.doPost(LocalLoginServlet.java:93)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1772)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:941)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:875)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:829)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:119)
>     at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:133)
>     at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:130)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$Context.call(GuiceFilter.java:203)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:130)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:123)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.java:44)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1751)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.doScope(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:597)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my problem was related to my jersey config. I had to add _ah/?.* to the ServletContainer.PROPERTY_WEB_PAGE_CONTENT_REGEX param so that it wouldn't interfere with /_ah/login being called by the dev server